# Does numpy.zeros() allow correct numba caching?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Numba does not cache when `numpy.zeros()` is called in the function. However, caching works properly with `numpy.zeros_like()`.

I cannot have numba to cache the function when `numpy.zeros()` is called in the function. The same function is successfully cached when `numpy.zeros()` is replaced by `numpy.zeros_like()`, and properly changing the argument.

```py
@jit('UniTuple(float64[:],4)(int32[:],int32[:],int32[:],int32[:],float64[:])',
     nopython=True, parallel=True, cache=True, fastmath=True, nogil=True)
def fun_rec(a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray, m: np.ndarray, n: np.ndarray, x: np.ndarray):
    l = int(len(x))
    rec_num = np.zeros_like(x)
    # not caching with rec_num = np.zeros(l)
    rec_avg = np.zeros_like(x)
    rec_err = np.zeros_like(x)
    rec_fnd = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i in range(l):
        if rec_num[i] != 0:
            continue
        for j in prange(i + 1, l):
            if (a[i] == m[j] and b[i] == n[j] and m[i] == a[j] and n[i] == b[j]):
                avg = (x[i] + x[j]) / 2
                err = abs(x[i] - x[j]) / abs(avg)
                rec_num[i] = j + 1
                rec_num[j] = i + 1
                rec_avg[i] = avg
                rec_avg[j] = avg
                rec_err[i] = err
                rec_err[j] = err
                rec_fnd[i] = 1
                rec_fnd[j] = 1
                break
    return(rec_num, rec_avg, rec_err, rec_fnd)
```

I was expecting numba to support `numpy.zeros()` as described in the documentation, no difference between `numpy.zeros()` and `numpy.zeros_like()` is described. I would like to know if the incorrect caching is related to possible errors in my code.

Comment: Are you specifying `dtype` with your `np.zeros()` calls? That may be what triggers the optimization.

Comment: Thank you, I tried without specifying the dtype (i.e., calling np.zeros(l)), the code works as expected but without caching the function. Do you think I should try to specify some dtype? Although default is np.float64, which should be the proper one for the given numba signature. Anyway, I'm ok with using np.zeros_like(), it is more to understand than a real need at this point.